# how to set format for individual columns of data table in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, vb6, dataset, vb6-migration

i have a crystal report with a data table bind as data source. i would like to set format for data in individual columns through program.

I am doing a migration project, vb 6 to c#. so i have the vb 6 code with me. i need an equivalent in c# for:

`Me.Sections(3).Controls("Column").DataFormat.Format = //give the format needed`

column 1 is the column i need to format.

Comment: `this.Sections[3].Controls["Column"].DataFormat.Format = //Format`

Comment: i cant use this because i am not writing the code in .cs of report . I have separately created a class file for writing the data binding part. and i want the **c# equivalent** of this line of code

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. The c# version of the code you shared is what I shared. Can you explain the use case with more details and relevant code?

Comment: i have shared the vb6 code line. not c#. I need the c# equivalent for the same. In vb6 i have a  crystal report with data field "column" and set a format for the field through the code snippet ` Me.Sections(3).Controls("Column").DataFormat.Format = //give the format needed`. Like this  in C#,  i am using a data set as data source in the crystal report designer and pass values to it from program. I need to format one of the field(i.e, a column of data table )from program as it is done in vb6.

Comment: Maria, @ChetanRanpariya's line IS the C# translation of the VB6 code. If you need something else its not clear in the question, and there are no other details of what problem you are having.  Is the main issue that you are not familiar with C#?

Comment: for setting any field in crystal report currently i am doing like this 
```crystalReport rpt = new crystalReport();```
 ```(TextObject)rpt.Section2.ReportObjects["FeildName"].Text = "Hello World"; ```

I am not able to access as  Chetan have mentioned.
Like this .```Sections[3].Controls["Column"]. ```
It is giving me compilation errors. If anybody is able to access fields like this, could you share how is it

Comment: you can access the Sections from ReportDefinition. Try with`rpt.ReportDefinition.Sections[3].ReportObjects["Column"] ...` You can find the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms225594(v=vs.90))